# Can't set attribute on array items that contain nodes

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner Javascripter and I want to run this script to randomly change the background color of boxes. This is my JS:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-3");

var innDivs = [];

colournumber = function() {
return(Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').slice(2, 8);
}

for (i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
innDivs[i] = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
innDivs[i].setAttribute("style","background-color:#"+colournumber());
}
```

But I'm getting the error that I can't setAttribute on innDivs[i]. Any ideas how I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/w8gLqghz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` get you a list of elements. It is the elements themselves that have the `setAttribute` method.
You'll have to iterate through the list and set each individual element's attribute;

```
for (i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
    innDivs[i] = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (j=0;j<innDivs[i].length;j++) {
        innDivs[i][j].setAttribute("style","background-color:#"+colournumber());
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/w8gLqghz/5/

Comment: That worked but I can't quite understand why mine didn't. What's inside innDivs[i]?
Is it a multidimensional array?

Comment: `innDivs[i]` is a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) i.e. a collection of html elements. The HTMLCollection object has no `setAttribute` method itself, to set the attributes of the elements inside the collection you'll have to expose each individual element, which is done in the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you would see if you look in the debugger, `innDivs` is empty (you never put anything in it).

Therefore, `innDivs[i]` doesn't exist.

Did you mean `divs`?

Comment: There is `innDivs[i] = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("div");`, but maybe that was an edit.